# How to convert string to UpperCamelCase in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to turn string into CamelCase fashion In Ruby. The question also applies to words with underscores.

For example:

```
"human" => "Human"
"little_human" => "LittleHuman"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails there is a `camelize` method. In ruby you can write the method on your own. Something like

```
def camelize(s)
  s.downcase.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join
end
```

Comment: use also like this @Ursus  "little_human".downcase.split("_").map(&:titleize).join
 => "LittleHuman"

Comment: @vijay13 this is a pure-ruby solution, `titleize` require Rails.

Answer (score 3):

With regexp:

```
def camelize(str)
  str.gsub(/(^.)|(_.)/) { |l| l[-1].upcase }
end
```

Comment: This returns `Little_Human`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Update answer.

Comment: `gsub(/(^|_)(.)/) { $2.upcase }` would also work if you don't mind global variables.

Comment: Nice refactoring, thanks @Stefan.